# Does media type affect fragmentation?

Tags: filesystems

How does filesystem fragmentation (non-contiguous data blocks) differ among mediae (RAM disk, HDD, floppy, what-have-you)?

For example, if I read and write to my a RAM disk the exact same bytes as I do to my hard disk across a period of time, will I see a different amount of filesystem fragmentation?

Comment: Assuming you are referring to reserving memory to be used as a storage medium then yes the fragmentation would still occur but it is a non-issue just like SSDs

Comment: Please define which type of "fragmentation" you're asking about.  Are you referring to non-contiguous data block?  Are you referring to wasted spaced by partially used blocks at the end of files?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_%28computing%29

Comment: @sawdust edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

The fragmentation doesn't depend on the medium per se. If you use a 1GB RAM disk with the same filesystem as a 1GB hard disk, the fragmentaten will be the same. But different filesystems have different fragmentation characteristics. FAT filesystem for example is much worse than modern filesystems. And a RAM disk probably uses a special filesystem. OTOH a RAM disk or flash memory don't suffer as much from fragmentation as a spinning disk, as they have mostly random access and it doesn't matter much if they access blocks from different areas of the disk or consecutive blocks.

Comment: Technically fragmentation is a problem ( it exists ) on flash media ( flash drives, ssd, ect ) but its existance does not change the access times of the drive.  The reason fragmentation is a problem on magnetic drive is how the mechanical operation of the drives work ( it spins (optical disk), or there is a platter and head (hdd) ) which fragmentation has a huge impact on.  I put odd in that statement because if optical disk fragmentation did exist it would be a problem because of how the laser reads different tracks.

Comment: A better answer would incorporate what kind of "fragmentation" it is explaining.

Comment: @Ramhound -- *"it spins (optical disk), or there is a platter and head (hdd)"* -- HDDs also "spin" and optical disks have a surface and use a "head" (that has seek and rotational latency just like a HDD).  The distinction between optical drive versus HDD is optical laser versus magnetic, and not spin or platter/head related.

Comment: @sawdust my statement was very generic on purpose.  I understand the platter disks also spin the difference an optical disc does not have fragmentation